Does generate conditions break integrals
$Assumptions = {Element[{t, t1, t2, t3, t4, \[Delta], \[CapitalOmega],
      h}, PositiveReals], Element[{j, k, l}, PositiveIntegers]};

Integrate[E^(-I (k (-t1 + t2) + 
    j (4 t1 - 4 t2 - t3 + t4)) \[Delta]), {t1, 0, (
  2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}, {t2, 0, t1}, {t3, 0, t2}, {t4, 0, t3}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]

Integrate[E^(-I (k (-t1 + t2) + 
    j (4 t1 - 4 t2 - t3 + t4)) \[Delta]), {t1, 0, (
  2 \[Pi])/\[Delta]}, {t2, 0, t1}, {t3, 0, t2}, {t4, 0, t3}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]

I think this is the minimum possible code to reproduce the issue. They both should give the same result but one returns ComplexInfinity or Indeterminate, while the other returns a closed form expression. Does anyone else get this?
I've tried to go through this integral term by term a bit more manually, and I tried to make mathematica avoid using sign[] and abs[], and I got the same result as the integral with generated conditions turned off. It seems that by the third integral mathematica starts to use sign[] and abs[] functions which in my opinion might not be necessary and make the whole thing more unwieldy, and it starts to use conditional expressions. Then towards the final integrals the conditional expressions which are only infinity in some special cases, somehow make the whole expression undefined.
It seems like a small issue but when doing nested integrals of thousands of terms, things really start to break down and I am not sure how.
It's also worth noting that if you substitute j->2 and k->4 before integrating, both return the same closed form expression. So there's no way that the result can be undefined for all values of j and k. I think it looks more like a bug

I've seen such cases before, where when adding GenerateConditions -> True different result or behavior can happen. This is because GenerateConditions -> True invokes different code path and runs code which otherwise will not run. There are few such cases in this forum but hard to search for these.  I think for integrate, it is set to true by default.

I get the same result as @Luca  .  I think it should be reported as a bug.
